# How do I show differences between local and remote files in Git?

Tags: git

Since I am new to Git, I have some trouble getting started (Git version 2.12.3).

I created on a server a file (in GitLab) which I can clone to a local directory.

```
git clone git@gitlab.server.com:/joe/myproject.git
```

All fine, and I have a local copy of the file. But when I change remote something to the file (from someone else or on the server), then I am not able to track or to see the changes on the local client, even if they are clearly visible on the master. Not with

```
git diff file1
```

or

```
git diff origin/master
```

or something else.

I have to fetch the file, merge it, and then I am able to see the newly edited content. Is it possible to observe and detect the new changes **before** fetching the new file?

Comment: To see the changes that others have made, you would need to `git pull` their changes. Only then can you compare it against the changes you have made.

Comment: @Lix, since a "pull" contains a "fetch" and a "merge" i would change the local sources, but i would investigate the difference *before* i do such changes.

Comment: you could just `git fetch origin` and then `git diff master..origin/master -- myfile.txt`

Comment: @efkin, that is working, than you!

Comment: @Coliban, i formulated the comment in terms of answer so other people can benefit. i guess also DanielTrugman answer is more than adequate. feel free to accept one of those please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to accomplish your needs, you need at least to `fetch` from your remote repository. And only then -and before you `merge`- you can `diff` between your `branch` and your `origin/branch`.

Answer (score 9):

I would do it like this:

```
git fetch origin master
```

And then I would do:

```
git diff master origin/master
```

In a more simplified way, to see the difference in your local and remote repository, the syntax would be like this:

```
git diff <masterbranch> <remotebranch>
```

There is also `git difftool` command which shows the difference in a UI environment if you have installed one, I have rarely used this, so it's kind of an uncharted area for me. Have fun.

Comment: @Mortensen  -- I removed the incorrect statement that git pull is equivalent to git fetch and git diff.   It is equivalent to git fetch and git merge.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to observe and detect the new changes **before** fetching the new file?

No, if you don't fetch the changes, your local repository is not aware of them.

> I have to fetch the file, merge it, and then I am able to see the newly edited content.

You don't have to merge it, only fetch it!

**Comparing**

If you want to compare a local path against the remote one, use:

```
git diff <repo>/<branch> -- <path>
```

For example:

```
git diff origin/master -- program.cpp
--- OR ---
git diff origin/master -- Utils/*
```

Comment: This is what the accepted answer should be.

Comment: `fatal: bad revision 'origin/master'`

Comment: @xyf, that's because your branch is probably not named `master`. Just use the right branch name.