# Is there a way to see difference between "upstream" and local repo before fetching in Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I use `git fetch upstream` to get the latest changes from upstream repo but I can't figure out how I could see the difference between my local copy and upstream. I need something like `git diff` or at least `git status` so I could see what files have been changed before fetching. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Before fetching, no. Before merging: yes, by fetching and then diffing `origin/your-branch` vs `your-branch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I show differences between local and remote files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786070/how-do-i-show-differences-between-local-and-remote-files-in-git)